# Meta badges in top-bar don't match those in profile

Tags: support, meta, badges

In Meta, my top bar looks like this

[image: My Meta Top Bar]

4x Silver, 13x Bronze = 17 total

But on my profile, it looks like this
[image: Meta profile badges]

2x Silver, 10x Bronze = 12 total

It's been a few days since any activity so I would have thought any caching would have caught up by now... any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Did you click "view more"...?

Comment: Ugh... teach me to ask questions on a Monday morning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge count in your profile is the number of **distinct** badges you have been awarded, whereas the number in your topbar/flair is the **total** number of badges you have been awarded including those that can be awarded multiple times.

If you count the list you have 12 badges, but have been awarded 3 twice and 1 three times (your current profile.

Adding these into your total gives the 17 in your topbar/flair.

Answer (score 4):

[image: badges!]

```
8 + 2 + 3 = 13 (Bronze)

2 + 2 = 4  (Silver)
```

Comment: My brain just didn't pick up the greyed out "xN" element. Feel like a right numpty right now.